# How to create a view joining the following tables? I want to find cities that have the same name as students' first names

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `assignment-one-db`.student;

INSERT INTO city (id, firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES (1, 'Maria', 'Popescu', 'maria.popescu@yahoo.com');

SELECT * FROM `assignment-one-db`.city;

INSERT INTO city (city_id, name, latitude, longitude)
VALUES (1, 'Sibiu', 13, 14);
```

Comment: There are many ways to join two tables. What exactly do you want the result to be?

Comment: I want to create an inner join :)

Comment: An inner join based on what? The two tables seem unrelated, they have no common columns or any columns that look similar.

Comment: For example, I can change in the table city the column firstname with name, and I want to  create an inner join based on the name of the tables.

Comment: So you want to find cities that have the same name as students' first names? Please edit the question and add that info.

Comment: Homework?  Learn about `JOIN...ON` syntax.  Do not use the old `FROM a,b WHERE ...` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW V AS
SELECT cty.name
  FROM `assignment-one-db`.student st, 
       `assignment-one-db`.city cty
  WHERE st.firstname = cty.name;
```

Comment: Change to the new `JOIN .. ON ..` syntax.